# поиск "двойных" совпадений в "трехмерном" массиве

Tags: алгоритм, поиск

Имеется большой массив, в каждой строчке ровно три числа, каждое число 32битное.
Вопрос - какой самый быстрый алгоритм поиска "двойных" совпадений ?

Например, если массив

1 2 33

1 3 5

2 3 8

2 7 33

2 33 1012

то найтись должны три строчки "1 2 33", "2 7 33" и "2 33 1012",
так как "двойным" совпаденьем является "2" и "33".
(естественно, нужно найти все-все различные имеющиеся совпаденья)

Пока что я это реализовал так:
создаётся три вспомогательных массива.
В первом числа в строках сортируются как мин-сред-макс,
во втором мин-макс-сред, в третьем сред-макс-мин.
Потом массивы объединяются в один, массив сортируется и идёт построчная сверка первых двух чисел.

Есть ли более быстрый и оптимальный алгоритм такового поиска ?!

Comment: А ничего, 2 и 33 – вообще не совпадение?

Answer (score 3):

Я бы сделал через словарь:

- все три сочетания цифр в отсортированном виде используются как ключи словаря, по которым добавляется текущая комбинация цифр
- берутся значения этого словаря, в которых получилось больше одного элемента
  Вроде бы сложность `O(1)` должна получиться.

```py
from collections import defaultdict

data = """\
1 2 33
1 3 5
2 3 8
2 7 33
2 33 1012""".split('\n')

d = defaultdict(list)
for line in data:
    numbers = tuple(sorted(line.split()))
    for i1, i2 in ((0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2)):
        d[(numbers[i1], numbers[i2])].append(line)

for val in d.values():
    if len(val) > 1:
        print(val)
```

Вывод:

```
['1 2 33', '2 7 33', '2 33 1012']
```